# How to pass parameters dynamically in WorldPay payment integration in dotnet MVC 4 source code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, worldpay

I have tried this in **view** which is working fine but not able to pass these static parameters dynamically from **controller**, any MVC expert friend please help me out in my situation, I'll be very thankful for assistance.

View code:

```
<form action="https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" name="BuyForm" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="instId"  value="211616"><!-- The "instId" value "211616" should be replaced with the Merchant's own installation Id -->
<input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="abc123"><!-- This is a unique identifier for merchants use. Example: PRODUCT123 -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP"><!-- Choose appropriate currency that you would like to use -->
<input type="hidden" name="amount"  value="400">
<input type="hidden" name="desc" value="Product-1,Product-2,Product-3,Product-4">
<input type="hidden" name="testMode" value="100">

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Try using a `Tightly coupled/ Model Based view`

Answer (score 0):

Try using model based view like below

```
@model Merchant

@using (Html.BeginForm("action","controller",htmlAttr))
{

@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.InstallationId);
//etc

}
```